# Excel get Day Name gives an Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have been stuck at this weird error with excel 2010. I have the following data at cell A4 which is a reference to another cell B1, which is a start date entered by user, and I am trying to  get day name by using the formula 
`=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B4),"Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa")`, yet it gives an error with no real clues. Also I have tried

```
=Text(B4, "dddd")
```

and it gives an error as well.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Did you try using `;` instead of `,`? AFAIK the one you should use depend on your regional settings.

Comment: adding ; did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, depending on regional settings, you should use semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` as separator in formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error myself. The problem is not in the `CHOOSE` function, but in the `WEEKDAY` function.

It turns out that the `WEEKDAY` function is expecting very strict date formats and is influenced by the system's date format.

As stated in the cell's date format panel:

> NOTE:  Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) will change if you change the regional date and time settings in Control Panel. Formats without an asterisk won’t change.

The solution is to change the date cell's format to a **strict** date format, one of the formats in the list **without a * symbol**, and then entering a date in the format of `01-JAN-2018`.

As you can see in the image below, this solved my problem:

[image]

Comment: It gave the same error; however, Like @Egan Wolf suggested, replacing , with ; did the trick!

Comment: @user2597012 Great, happy you solved this issue. I'm gonna keep my answer posted anyway since it did solve my issue.